# When drawing a freehand line with the cursor, how do I make it a dashed line?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am using Flex 4 and AS3 and I am trying to make it so that the user can draw a freehand line with the cursor - I have this part done.

However, I also need the line to be a dashed line instead of one solid line like it is now.  below is my code I am using.  I have found some examples on how to do this, but they are all for straight lines, not for a freehand line.

Can anyone help me accomplish this?

**Class File (DrawingArea):**

```
package
{
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder;

public class DrawingArea extends UIComponent
{
    private var isDrawing:Boolean = false;
    private var x1:int;
    private var y1:int;
    private var x2:int;
    private var y2:int;

    public var drawColor:uint = 0x0000FF;

    public function DrawingArea()
    {
        super();

        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(event:FlexEvent):void {
            graphics.clear();

            graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0.00001);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
            graphics.endFill();
        });

        addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown );
        addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove );
        addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);

        function mouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
            x1 = mouseX;
            y1 = mouseY;
            isDrawing = true;
        }
        function mouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if (!event.buttonDown)
            {
                isDrawing = false;
            }

            x2 = mouseX;
            y2 = mouseY;
            if (isDrawing)
            {
                graphics.lineStyle(1, drawColor);
                graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
                graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
            }
        }
        function mouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
            isDrawing = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Application MXML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<DrawingArea id="drawingArea" xmlns="*" width="100%" height="100%"/>

</s:Application>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class DrawingArea extends UIComponent
{
    private var isDrawing:Boolean = false;

```
public var drawColor:uint = 0x0000FF;

private var start:Point = new Point;
private var end:Point = new Point;

public function DrawingArea()
{
    super();
 }
    addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(event:FlexEvent):void {
        graphics.clear();


    });

    addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown );
    addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove );
    addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);

    function mouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {

            start = new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);


    }
    function mouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
        grahics.clear();
        end =  new Point(this.mouseX-5, this.mouseY-5);
        graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000,2);
        drawDashedLine(graphics,start,end,true);

    }
    function mouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {

    }



  function drawDashedLine(g:Graphics, start:Point, end:Point, 
                dashed:Boolean = false, dashLength:Number = 6):void {
        g.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
        if (dashed) {

            var total:Number = Point.distance(start, end);

            if (total <= dashLength) {

                g.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
            } else {

                var step:Number = dashLength / total;
                var dashOn:Boolean = false;
                var p:Point;
                for (var t:Number = step; t <= 1; t += step) {
                    p = getLinearValue(t, start, end);
                    dashOn = !dashOn;
                    if (dashOn) {
                        g.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                    } else {
                        g.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                    }
                }

                dashOn = !dashOn;
                if (dashOn && !end.equals(p)) {
                    g.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
                }
            }
        } else {

            g.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks - it works if you move the mouse fast, but I now have to figure out how to make it do the same if you move the mouse slowly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: i already use this code for my project and working perfectly according to the movement of mouse. I rebuild this code for your question. Please debug this code find out where error showing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect solution for this. But a mathematical solution can provide a similar experience. when drawing a line with x1 y1 point and x2 y2 point, we can find two more points between these points in the same line. This way the line gets divided into three sections. we can apply alternating colors to each section.

To arrive at the line equation with two points use (y - y1)/(y2 - y1) = (x - x1)/(x2 - x1). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

Using resultant equation and substituting values to it, we can find the two points, I mentioned above.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution:

http://blog.alegitimatebusiness.com/2007/11/07/as2-as3-draw-a-dotted-rounded-corner-box/